# How to Validate a Collection of annotated objects in XML

Tags: java, hibernate-validator

I was looking over [this post of using JSR-303 to validate a collection of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7136152/249016). The solution works great with annotations, but I can't seem to get it to work with the Hibernate Validator XML formatted configuration.

For example, I have code similar to this:

```
public class DataSet
{
    Collection<Data> dataCollection;
    public Collection<Data> getDataCollection() {...}
}
```

From there, I have a custom validator/annotation `DataValidator`/`@ValidData`.

In XML, I do this first:

```
<bean class="DataSet"
    ignore-annotations="true">
    <field name="dataCollection">
        <valid/>
        <constraint annotation="ValidData"/>
    </field>
</bean>
```

However, I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: No validator could be found for type: java.util.Collection<DataSet>
```

So I swap the `<valid>` tag with the `<constraint>` one in the XML. It seems this is not valid with the XSD schema and the XML can no longer be parsed.

```
<bean class="DataSet"
    ignore-annotations="true">
    <field name="dataCollection">
        <constraint annotation="ValidData"/>
        <valid/>
    </field>
</bean>

Exception in thread "main" javax.validation.ValidationException: Error parsing mapping file.
```

Does anyone know how I can use XML to validate this collection with must custom validator?

Comment: Based on the first exception I'd say that there is no constraint validator for `@ValidData` for the type `Collection`. What validators do you have for that constraint?

Comment: For example sake, @ValidData can be assumed to be a custom constraint annotation. DataValidator would be the custom validator linked via the annotation.

Answer (score 1):

The key was adding a class-level constraint annotation in the XML to the Data POJO itself.

```
<bean class="DataSet"
    ignore-annotations="true">
    <field name="dataCollection">
        <valid/>
    </field>
</bean>

<bean class="Data" ignore-annotations="true">
     <class>
          <constraint annotation="ValidData"/>
     </class>
</bean>
```