# javax-validation annotation is not working for member variables that is declared as another ObjectType

Tags: spring-boot, bean-validation

I have added annotations in the parent class.
It is working fine.

But it is not working in the member variables that is declared as another Object type. It is validating:

- `orderId` from base class
- `referenceNumber` from `MarchantApplicationRequest`
- `@NotEmpty` annotation at `customerRequests` field in `MerchantApplicationRequest`.

But it is not validating `customerRoleType` in `CustomerRequest`.

Also, I would like to add `@NotBlank` annotation in `customerRequests`. But it is not taking this, though it is taking `@NotEmpty` annotation.

#### Class `MerchantApplicationRequest`

```java
@JsonIngnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=false) 
public class  MerchantApplicationRequest extends IomBaseDTO {
    @NotEmpty(message="customerRequests is mandatory")
    private List<CustomerRequest> customerRequests;
    @NotBlank(message="referenceNumber is mandatory")
    private String referenceNumber ;
}
```

#### Class `CustomerRequest`

```java
public class  CustomerRequest  { 
    @NotBlank(message="customerRoleType is mandatory")
    private String customerRoleType ;
}
```

#### Controller class

Method where to apply validation:

```java
    @PostMapping("/orderDetail")
    public void orderDetail(@Valid @RequestBody MerchantApplicationRequest request) {
       
        try {
            iOrderService.updateProductDetail(request);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // ...
        }
    }
```

Here is my JSON payload:

```json
    {
       "orderId" : 101,
       "referenceNumber" : "123",
       "customerRequests" : [ {
         "customerRoleType" : null
       }]
    }
```

I am using in `pom.xml` of Spring Boot application:

```xml
<dependency> 
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: You missed @Valid annotation on customerRequests parameter. please add it.

Comment: it is not validating as you have not specified that it should be validated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to cascade the validation you have to add the `@Valid` annotation:

```java
@Valid
@NotEmpty(message="customerRequests is mandatory")
private List<CustomerRequest> customerRequests;
```

Please read more about cascading in the Hibernate Validation documentation: [Example 2.11: Cascaded validation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/6.2/reference/en-US/html_single/#example-cascaded-validation)

Answer (score 0):

Using [bean-validation](https://beanvalidation.org/) (`javax.validation`), you can add validation to elements of collections.

#### Using Bean-Validation 1.0

```java
@JsonIngnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=false) 
public class  MerchantApplicationRequest extends IomBaseDTO {

    @NotEmpty(message="customerRequests is mandatory")
    @Valid
    private List<CustomerRequest> customerRequests;

    @NotBlank(message="referenceNumber is mandatory")
    private String referenceNumber ;
}
```

See also:

- [JSR 303: How to Validate a Collection of annotated objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106772/jsr-303-how-to-validate-a-collection-of-annotated-objects)
- LogicBig Tutorial: [Collection Validation](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-ee-tutorial/bean-validation/collection-validation.html)

#### Alternative since Bean-Validation 2.0

In Java 8 generic types can also be validated by prepending the annotation before the type inside the diamond-operator, e.g. `<@Valid CustomerRequest>`. This is a more concise way of defining per-element validation. It has the same effect like the traditional way, validates every given element  as defined in the class (`CustomerRequest`).

See also:

- [java/beans validation - collection/map does not contain nulls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27984137/java-beans-validation-collection-map-does-not-contain-nulls/33481403#33481403)
- Baeldung Tutorial: [Validating Container Elements with Bean Validation 2.0](https://www.baeldung.com/bean-validation-container-elements)